# When I attempt to runserver, why do I get an ImportError Reason: image not found?

Tags: django, postgresql, psycopg2

I upgraded from osX 10.7 to 10.9 and all my PostgreSQL database calls started failing.

I upgraded to psycopg2 version 2.5.2  via
$ sudo pip install --upgrade psycopg2

When I try to runserver, I get an importError.

```
$ python manage.py runserver    
    ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so, 2): Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libpq.5.4.dylib  
      Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so  
      Reason: image not found
```

What does this mean?
It seems that Python is attempting to load:
 /usr/local/lib/libpq.5.4.dylib

But the file is not there, how do I correct this?

HOW I FIXED IT:
It seems postgreSQL was looking for a file in the wrong location.

So, I installed PostgreSQL 9.3 from a binary.
I think created a symbolic link to the *.dynlib file.

ln -s /Library/PostgreSQL/9.3/lib/libpq.5.6.dylib /usr/local/lib/libpq.5.4.dylib

Comment: Do you get the same error if you run `import psycopg2` from the Python interpreter? Also, which version of Python is being used?

Comment: Yes I do get the same error. I'm going to add details to my original question. Python-2.7.6

Answer (score 1):

`libpq.5.4.dylib` should reside in `/Library/PostgreSQL/9.1/lib/`.

Try creating a link from `/usr/local/lib/libpq.5.4.dylib` to  `/Library/PostgreSQL/9.1/lib/libpq.5.4.dylib`

I did note that I have no such link in my own `/usr/local/lib`, but then I am running 10.6.8.